# Sending notification to the user on database change

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, notifications

I am building a cafeteria management system in which there are two types of users;customres & counter owners.

For each dish offered in cafeteria, there is aunique dish.id associated to it.

Till now, I have dome something like student sends a POST request with dish,id and counter number to a URL which updates the "orders table'(which has PK as id). When the dish is prepared, the counter owner presses "Prepeared" button.

At this point, I want the customer whose order is next to what is prepared to get notified that "Your order preparation is in progress."

How should I do it?
One way is to simply make a view which has its argument as customer.id & status and it replies with True or Flase. I can simply poll the URL and provide the notification if I recieve True.

**But, I feel like polling is not a better approach as there will be so many customers logged in and each will poll to the server which is not acceptible**.
Any better way?

Comment: Polling (1 HTTP request) vs full page post back(10+?) looks pretty good to me. Facebook does it. Can you imagine how many users it has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends what you really need.

If notification can be sent ad part of user activity, simply add a user message, and it will be displayed whenever user do an action on the page. [django.contrib.messages](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) plus few lines in your main html template will do it.

But if you want the notification to be interactive - you can use one of the [few PUSH options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)

Interesting links:

- [wikipedia on reverse ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Ajax)
- [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

From the servers side, there are few options available, the simplest is [Green Unicorn](http://gunicorn.org/). Using it will allow you to have few thousands connections open and managed by only few processes.

Answer (score 1):

I don;t know if u understood corectly but i think you should use websockets

```
 http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of a "push" without recurring polling would be "[long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling)", where the client starts an request and gets the answer as soon as it's available. You have to use a well scaling server anyway but it doesn't get hammered at least hammered all the time.

There are better but more complicated ways for server pushes, have a look at the article I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways...

1. Override your related models admin.py **save** methods like [it described in here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model)
2. You can use signals [as it described in here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save)

Using admin.save_model is easier and suit your needs. Since you have table_id's, you may set that tables order status to "preparing".

Answer (score -1):

As we cannot push data over http, I think polling is the only option left.

You can you a ajax request to poll, Which can be used to update some other stats ( if any ) as well to make it more interactive :)

Comment: there is an option to push over the internet. Look at the stacoferflow code itself... question how to do it :)

Comment: I am talking about pushing data from web server to client ( browser ) and not the other way.

Comment: Those are some mechanisms to achieve push effect over a protocol which in theory doesn't support push natively, isn't it? Can we say http "supports" push? I don't think so. Thats why google is experimenting with http://www.chromium.org/spdy . HTTP is exclusively client-initiated requests protocol